# React Native: borderTopLeft(Right)Radius behave differently on iOS and Android

Tags: react-native

I would like to have a semi-circle as you can see on the right side of the screenshot ( Android ). However, the result looks differently on iOS. Looks like borderTopStartRadius and borderTopEndRadius work differently depending on the platform. The style class is quite simlple and is applied on View component:

```
logo_semiCircle: {
width: 150,
height: 75,
backgroundColor: "#fff",
borderTopStartRadius: 75,
borderTopEndRadius: 75, 
}
```

[image]

What is the possible work-around for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Style

```
footer_logo_semiCircle: {
width: 150,
height: 75,
backgroundColor: "#fff",
borderTopStartRadius: 75,
borderTopEndRadius: 75, 
overflow: 'hidden',
}
```

I got a reference from here [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13760)